# Git is pushing to wrong remote branch

Tags: git, git-push

What I have done:

```
$ git clone git@github.com:myuser/doctrine-extensions.git
$ cd doctrine-extensions
$ git checkout -b rollback_positions origin/master
```

Then I have made some changes, committed and status says:

```
 $ git status
 On branch rollback_positions
 Your branch is ahead of 'origin/master' by 1 commit.
    (use "git push" to publish your local commits)
```

Now I want to push to the remote `origin` to a new branch `rollback_positions`. But Git does not create the new remote branch, but uses `master`:

```
$ git push origin rollback_positions
Counting objects: 88, done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (16/16), done.
Writing objects: 100% (17/17), 4.50 KiB | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 17 (delta 10), reused 0 (delta 0)
To git@github.com:myuser/doctrine-extensions.git
   b1c3643..6a09dc9  rollback_positions -> master
```

What is wrong? It should be `rollback_positions -> rollback_positions`.

Comment: Is there a remote branch named `rollback_positions`?

Comment: No, but it should be created.

Comment: Yes it should get created. Try with `-u` which will set up an upstream branch.`git push -u origin rollback_positions`

Comment: Does not help. Git says: "Branch rollback_positions set up to track remote branch master from origin. Everything up-to-date"

Comment: Try specifying remote name explicitly `git push -u origin rollback_positions:rollback_positions`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
git checkout -b rollback_positions origin/master
```

sets the upstream branch of `rollback_positions` to `origin/master`. You can specify remote name explicitly while pushing:

```
git push -u origin rollback_positions:rollback_positions
```

Option `-u` will set upstream. You can also use `--set-upstream` and `--unset-upstream` to change `upstream`.
To avoid that next time use:

```
git checkout --no-track -b rollback_positions origin/master
```

as [Jubobs](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2541573/jubobs) said.